# Redux Framework custom field

Tags: wordpress, redux-framework

I've used the redux build to download the admin folder to include on a custom plugin.
Everything works OK.

I'm trying to create a custom field, using the custom_field bootstrap, but it's not loaded.
I've put it on the extension folder, inside the admin folder, and then added this custom field to the section:

```
array(
                        'id'        => 'opt-custom-field',
                        'type'      => 'custom_field',
                        'compiler'  => 'true',
                        'title'     => __('Example field', 'redux-framework-demo'),
                        'subtitle'  => __('Example field subtitle', 'redux-framework-demo'),
                    ),
```

When i access to the Admin dashboard, only the title and subtitle shows up and nothing else that is printed in the render function inside the custom field class.

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to run it via a hook not just the files.

Have you tried the extension boilerplate? 
https://github.com/ReduxFramework/extension-loader   -   To load the extension
https://github.com/ReduxFramework/extension-boilerplate   -   Your extension boilerplate.

Comment: P.S. Lead dev of Redux here.

Comment: Yes, I've used the redux builder to create and download the admin folder to my plugin, and after that, downloaded the boilerplate to the extension folder inside admin. I though that i just needed to put it there and after that, the extention loader (that cames with admin folder) would search for each extension and load it.. What kind of hook are you talking about?

Comment: It's best for you to post on our issue tracker. It's easier to find answers there and we'll do what we can to help.